# OCI -22303: type not "OE". "CUST_ADDRESS_TYPE"

Tags: database, oracle

I have created Virtual Private Database (VPD) policy to oe.customers table that if the customer service department users login to the database as an Account Managers they only will be able to see information related to the customers attached to their account and not all customers information (i.e. if the account manager executes following SQL statement select * from customers; he/she will be able to see only customers who are attached to his/her account.

after completion of my VPD if I login as a account manager and search for

```
Select * from oe.customers
```

I am getting error message

> OCI -22303: type not "OE". "CUST_ADDRESS_TYPE" not found.

however if I search like

```
select (column) from oe.customer
```

query successfully returns my values.

below I have given all my sql command which I used for creating my VPD.

Please help me how can I get result for

```
Select * from oe.customers
```

as a account manager such as Account1/passowrd

Connect sys/oracle as sysdba

```
GRANT CREATE SESSION, CREATE ANY CONTEXT, CREATE PROCEDURE, CREATE TRIGGER, ADMINISTER DATABASE TRIGGER TO sysadmin_vpd IDENTIFIED BY password;
GRANT EXECUTE ON DBMS_SESSION TO sysadmin_vpd;
GRANT EXECUTE ON DBMS_RLS TO sysadmin_vpd;


GRANT CREATE SESSION TO Account1 IDENTIFIED BY password;
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO Account2 IDENTIFIED BY password;
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO Account3 IDENTIFIED BY password;
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO Account4 IDENTIFIED BY password;



CONNECT oe/oe


CREATE TABLE oe.Account_mgr (
 account_mgr_id    NUMBER(6), 
 account_name  VARCHAR2(20));


INSERT INTO oe.Account_mgr VALUES (145, 'Account1');
INSERT INTO oe.Account_mgr VALUES (147, 'Account2');
INSERT INTO oe.Account_mgr VALUES (148, 'Account3');
INSERT INTO oe.Account_mgr VALUES (149, 'Account4');


GRANT SELECT ON oe.customers TO sysadmin_vpd;

GRANT SELECT ON oe.customers TO Account1;
GRANT SELECT ON oe.customers TO Account2;
GRANT SELECT ON oe.customers TO Account3;
GRANT SELECT ON oe.customers TO Account4;








Connect sysadmin_vpd/password



CREATE OR REPLACE CONTEXT CUSTOMER_CTX USING CUSTOMER_CTX _PKG;



CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE CUSTOMER_CTX _PKG IS 
  PROCEDURE SET_ACCNUM;
 END;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY CUSTOMER_CTX _PKG IS
  PROCEDURE SET_ACCNUM
  AS
    ACCNUM NUMBER;
  BEGIN
     SELECT ACCOUNT_MGR_ID INTO ACCNUM FROM OE.ACCOUNT_MGR
        WHERE ACCOUNT_NAME = SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER');
     DBMS_SESSION.SET_CONTEXT('CUSTOMER_CTX ', 'ACCOUNT_MGR_ID', ACCNUM);
  EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN NULL;
  END SET_ACCNUM;
END;
/




CREATE TRIGGER SET_ACCNUM_CTX_TRIG AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE
 BEGIN
  SYSADMIN_VPD.CUSTOMER_CTX _PKG.SET_ACCNUM;
 END;
/




SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('CUSTOMER_CTX ', 'ACCOUNT_MGR_ID') ACCNUM FROM DUAL;







CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ACC_MGR (
  schema_p   IN VARCHAR2,
  table_p    IN VARCHAR2)
 RETURN VARCHAR2
 AS
  CUSTOMER_PREDICATE VARCHAR2 (400);
 BEGIN
  CUSTOMER_PREDICATE:= 'account_mgr_id = SYS_CONTEXT(''CUSTOMER_CTX '', ''ACCOUNT_MGR_ID'')'; 
 RETURN CUSTOMER_PREDICATE;
END;
/






BEGIN
 DBMS_RLS.ADD_POLICY (
  object_schema    => 'OE', 
  object_name      => 'CUSTOMERS', 
  policy_name      => 'CUSTOMERS_POLICY', 
  function_schema  => 'SYSADMIN_VPD',
  policy_function  => 'ACC_MGR', 
  statement_types  => 'SELECT');
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type CUST_ADDRESS_TYPE  in customers table needs to be given grant separately

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON CUST_ADDRESS_TYPE TO  Account1;
GRANT EXECUTE ON CUST_ADDRESS_TYPE TO  Account2;
GRANT EXECUTE ON CUST_ADDRESS_TYPE TO  Account3;
GRANT EXECUTE ON CUST_ADDRESS_TYPE TO  Account4;
```

**Update1**:- In order for other accounts to view details of the oe.customer table we can use the  predicate which if null returns all the rows in oe.customer

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ACC_MGR (
schema_p   IN VARCHAR2,
table_p    IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN VARCHAR2
  AS
CUSTOMER_PREDICATE VARCHAR2 (400);
BEGIN
  IF SYS_CONTEXT('CUSTOMER_CTX', 'ACCOUNT_MGR_ID') IS NOT NULL
  THEN
  CUSTOMER_PREDICATE:= 'account_mgr_id = SYS_CONTEXT(''CUSTOMER_CTX '', ''ACCOUNT_MGR_ID'')'; 
  END IF;
  RETURN CUSTOMER_PREDICATE;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thank you very much but the problem is now other user are not able to access oe.customers table. even though I connect as a oe/oe (owner of oe.customers table ) and run select * from oe.customers result showing "no row selected". Could you please help me

Comment: insert one row in INSERT INTO oe.Account_mgr VALUES (150, 'oe'); and use  CUSTOMER_PREDICATE:= 'account_mgr_id = decode(SYS_CONTEXT(''CUSTOMER_CTX '', ''ACCOUNT_MGR_ID''),150,account_mgr_id,SYS_CONTEXT(''CUSTOMER_CTX '', ''ACCOUNT_MGR_ID''))';

Comment: I have given an example of 150 for oe for reference use a number to insert in account_mgr for oe which is not a valid account mgr id

Comment: actually I want to create this VPD that if account_mgr connect to database he only able to see details related to his account in oe.customers table however if any other user login to database and do a select statement able to see all the details of customers as like oe user. Can I create any policy like if only account manager has restricted access but other user able to see without any restriction.